# Unable to call setState of Flutter Stateful Widget from a static method

Tags: flutter

I have this following code where I am displaying a listview, and this listview takes data from a list, which can be dynamically updated from the `onConnect()` method of `STOMP`.
So this onConnect method is expected to be static.

Now, when I receive data from WebSocket, this onConnect method is invoked, which inserts the value in the list. But the listview doesn't get the update.
I am unable to call `setState()` so that the widget is re-rendered with new data as this `onConnect()` method is static.

Any solution for this.

```
List<ChatEntity> chats;
String chatRoomId;
String currentUserEmail;

class Chat extends StatefulWidget {

  Chat(String chatRoomIdC, String currentUserEmailC) {
    chatRoomId = chatRoomIdC;
    currentUserEmail = currentUserEmailC;
  }

  @override
  _ChatState createState() => _ChatState();
}

class _ChatState extends State<Chat> {
  TextEditingController messageEditingController = new TextEditingController();
 
  _ChatState() {
    client.activate();
  }

  StompClient client = StompClient(
    config: StompConfig(
        url: 'ws://localhost:8080/ws',
        onConnect: onConnectCallback,
        onWebSocketError: (dynamic error) => print(error.toString())),
  );

  static onConnectCallback(StompClient client, StompFrame connectFrame) {
    client.subscribe(
        destination: '/topic/messages/$chatRoomId',
        headers: {},
        callback: (frame) {
          response(frame);
        });
  }

  static response(StompFrame frame) {
    String response = frame.body;
    final parsed = json.decode(response).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    chats.insert(
        0,
        parsed
            .map<ChatEntity>((json) => ChatEntity.fromJson(json))
            .toList()[0]);

 // call setState here to re- render the widget
  }

  Widget chatMessages() {
    return ListView.builder(
        reverse: true,
        itemCount: chats == null ? 0 : chats.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return MessageTile(
            message: chats[index].message,
            sendByMe: currentUserEmail == chats[index].sentBy,
          );
        });
  }

  addMessage() {
    if (messageEditingController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      Map<String, dynamic> chatMessageMap = {
        "chatroomId": chatRoomId,
        "sentBy": currentUserEmail,
        "message": messageEditingController.text
      };
      client.send(
          destination: '/app/chat',
          body: jsonEncode(chatMessageMap),
          headers: {});

      setState(() {
        messageEditingController.text = "";
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    DatabaseMethods.getChats(chatRoomId).then((val) {
      setState(() {
        chats = val;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

// ignore the build method as it just contains a Scaffold.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use or access `setState` method you need to be inside of instance methods, not static (class) methods. So `response` and `onConnectCallback` methods shouldn't be static in this case. Because the `StompClient` refers to those methods, I would create a `StompClient client` instance when instantiating the widget (i.e. in constructor):

```
class _ChatState extends State<Chat> {
  TextEditingController messageEditingController = new TextEditingController();
  
  StompClient client;
 
  // Create a StompClient instance when creating new state
  _ChatState() {
    client = StompClient(
      config: StompConfig(
        url: 'ws://localhost:8080/ws',
        onConnect: onConnectCallback,
        onWebSocketError: (dynamic error) => print(error.toString())),
    );
    client.activate();
  }
 
  onConnectCallback(StompClient client, StompFrame connectFrame) {
    ...
  }

  response(StompFrame frame) {
    ...
    // HERE YOU SHOULD BE ABLE TO USE setState() METHOD
  }
...
```

Comment: Invalid reference to 'this' expression. in onConnect: this.onConnectCallback . Getting this error when tried the above code

Comment: Also getting this error if I remove StompClient parameter from onConnectCallback ... The argument type 'dynamic Function(StompFrame)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(StompClient, StompFrame)'.

Comment: Getting this error now : [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Unimplemented handling of static target arity change